# What would be the advantage for using the following statements?

Tags: c#, default

Recently, I ran into the following lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = default(StringBuilder);
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

I would simply write the statement(s) like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

What would be the advantage for using default(StringBuilder) statements?

Based on all the great feedback, I came up with a new question.

**EDIT:**
Can you see an advantage or disadvantage to doing something like this?  (it does compile)

```
var sb = default(StringBuilder);
```

Again like was mentioned I believe we are looking at whether there is a scope issue or not, but the biggest problem might be objects not getting initialized properly.  what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

In general, nothing.  There is no reason to initialize the variable, then set it in the next line of code.  Your second statement is cleaner.

There are few reasons to split declaration and assignment.  This typically is only required if there are scoping issues involved, such as trying to use exception handling around the assignment:

```
StringBuilder sb = null;

try
{
    // Using a statement that may throw
    sb = GetAStringBuilder();
}
catch
{
    //...
}

// The compiler will warn about a potentially 
// uninitalized variable here without the default assignment
if (sb != null)  
{
    //...
```

In this case, you need to split the two because your doing the assignment within a local scope (the `try`).

If this isn't the case, then it's better to keep them together.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is correct, even if your conclusion is. `StringBuilder sb; try { sb = GetAStringBuilder(); } finally { Console.WriteLine("in finally"); } if (sb != null) { ... }` This does require a separate *declaration*, but does not require separate *initialisation*. The reason separate initialisation *is* required in your example is because the `if (sb != null)` could otherwise be executed when `sb` hasn't been set.

Comment: @hvd Yes - that was my point - you'll get issues if you have local scoping about using uninitialized variables unless you initialize "before" your main initialization.

Comment: The point I'm making is that I do not initialise `sb` in the code in my previous comment, and do not need to, even though I assign to it in a local scope later. Note the lack of any `= null` between the `StringBuilder sb` and the `;`.

Comment: @hvd The compiler will complain and provide a warning in your code about using an uninitialized variable (in `if (sb != null)`), since not all code paths set a value to sb.

Comment: No, it won't. There is no code path that reaches the `if` without setting `sb`. You used `catch`, I used `finally`. Either the assignment succeeds, or `GetAStringBuilder()` throws an exception causing execution to leave the current function.

Comment: @hvd Oh, yeah - with finally, it doesn't  - with a catch, though, it does.  Even an if statement can cause it.  My point was that doing the assignment within a local scope, if the variable lives beyond the scope, can require splitting declaration and assignment.

Comment: Yes, and that was what I objected to: it doesn't matter whether the assignment happens within a local scope. What matters is whether the assignment can be skipped.

Comment: @hvd Yes - but that can *only happen* if you've got scoping issues.  I'm not saying that it always happens, but that scoping creates the potential for it to be a problem.

Comment: I would do it like: `StringBuilder sb; try { sb = GetAStringBuilder(); } catch { /* ... */ sb = null; }` Then after that, `sb` is assigned (but may be null of course). So the declaration is in an outer scope, the assignment in a local scope, like Reed says. However, I don't assign null to `sb` until I know it is needed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yeah - it was more pointing out that you often have to do *something* when you have scoping issues.  There's an implicit null assignment, btw, so there's no real reason to not set it to null if you're splitting the declaration and assignment...

Comment: "Yes - but that can only happen if you've got scoping issues" -- are you sure? What about `int a; int b = false ? a = 3 : 5;` The `a = 3` is an unevaluated subexpression, but there is no local scope. What about `int a; goto skip; a = 3; skip:`? Same story.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Fine, and I agree with your point. I just think it's easier to see the intention of the code if I don't set to null at the top, but wait until the end of the `catch` block (or `else` block or whatever). I don't care what happens runtime with my variable while it is not "definitely assigned" (according to the C# spec terminology), but you're probably right it will be null (even when the method is entered, _before_ the declaration of the local variable).

Comment: hvd, Reed Copsey, and Jeppe Stig Nielsen, thank you all for your comments, they were helpful to understanding the value or rather lack of value in using  `StringBuilder sb = default(StringBuilder);`  My preference is to use `StringBuilder sb = null; or StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` depending upon the scope of the variable.  I suppose the next question is which is the standard?  `StringBuilder sb = default(StringBuilder); or StringBuilder sb = null;`

Comment: @DanM Using `= null` is my preference.  `default()` is really only useful if you're working with generics, so you can do `default(T)` and support reference and value types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no advantage whatsoever; the second snippet is more concise and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using `default` comes up only when you develop a generic class that works with parametrized types. Sometimes, it is not known whether the type is a reference type or a value type or a struct. The `default` keyword returns `null` for reference types and `0` for numeric value types.

For more details, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: What you say is correct, but not an answer to the question. Regardless of whether `T` is a value type, `T t = default(T); t = new T();` can always be written as `T t = new T();`.

Comment: Correct, it's just my intention was to provide more general insight on the keyword.

Comment: Thank you Vlad for the additional insight, I had read that article before posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

The default keyword is often used with the initialization of generic types, where one cannot be certain whether  we are dealing with a value type (initialized e.g. to zero) or a reference type (initialized to null). As per other answers, in the example you provided,  there is little purpose either initializing StringBuilder and reassigning it immediately, nor using the default keyword.

In .net 3.5 there is one additional convention which you may come across, viz:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Here the type of sb is inferred from the RHS of the assignment.